# Django - AttributeError _committed

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a form that saves an image, and everything is working fine, but I want to be able to crop the image.  However, when I used Pillow to do this, I get a strange error that doesn't really give me much to go on.

> **Attribute error at /userprofile/addGame/**
>
> _committed

Looking further into the traceback, the following sections were highlighted:

[image]

[image]

I'm not really sure what this error means.  I think it has something to do with the `form.save(committed=False)`, and not being able to edit files after that point, but I'm not positive.  I can edit the user after that line using `form.user = request.user`, so I think it's the fact that I'm trying to change the image getting uploaded that is part of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but I recently experienced a similar problem.
The information in the question is somewhat incomplete but I had the same error.

Assuming the Error being

**File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 627, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)**

**AttributeError: _committed**

So the root problem lies with using PIL (Pillow). The function :

```
image = Image.open(self.cleaned_data['image'])
```

> We wrongly assume that the object **image** would continue to have the
>   instance of image throughout the function(clean_image in my case).

So in my code structure,

```
def clean_image(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['image']:
        try:
            image = Image.open(self.cleaned_data['image'])
            image.verify()
        except IOError:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The file is not an image'))
    return image
```

The error mentioned above is thrown after we execute this code. It is so because

> After several of the other PIL(pillow) functions we use, we need to
>   open the file again. Check this out in [pillow documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify)

As in the code above(last line),

`return image`

doesn't really return anything.

**To fix it**

Simply add ,

```
image = self.cleaned_data['image']
```

before the `return image` line.
Code looks like,

```
    except IOError:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('The file is not an image'))
    image = self.cleaned_data['image']    
return image
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue trying to save a model with an ImageFileField. My requirement was to save an image from a zip object.

Using pillow gave me the `AttributeError: _committed` error. Following is what worked for me:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

zf =  zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, mode='r')
image_list = zf.infolist()

Model.objects.create(img=ImageFile(zipObj.open(image_list[0])),
                     file_name=image_list[0].filename.split("/")[-1].strip(),
                               ...)
```